# How to merge and print two sorted arrays of ints

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to create a method that takes in two sorted int arrays and returns a new array that merges and resorts the two lists without using a sort function. I'm having trouble within my loop and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm currently getting the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at pack8.Assignment8Code.merge(Assignment8Code.java:20)
    at pack8.Assignment8Code.main(Assignment8Code.java:39)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Assignment8Code 
{   
    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {
        //Create the first two arrays with testing numbers
        arr1 = new int[5];
        arr2 = new int[3];
        //Create a new array that will fit the length of the two given arrays
        int[] sortedArray = new int[(arr1.length + arr2.length)];
        //Create starting index values to check all arrays and merge
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        //Test to see if the given arrays are populated
        while(index1 < arr1.length || index2 < arr2.length)
        {
            //Check to see which array starts with the higher number
            if(arr1[index1] < arr2[index2])
            {
                sortedArray[index1] = arr1[index1];
                index1++;
            }
            else
            {
                sortedArray[index2] = arr2[index2];
                index2++;
            }
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you immediately discarding the parameters? Remove those two `new int` statements. --- `while(index1 < arr1.length || index2 < arr2.length)` means that you continue even if *one* of them is at-end. so why didn't you expect `if(arr1[index1] < arr2[index2])` to fail when one is at-end? You can only compare the 2 values, if both inputs have values left to be compared.

Comment: You also need to keep a separate index into the output array instead of using either `index1` or `index2`.

Comment: @Kevin or use index1 + index2

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should use a separate method for testing, assigning `arr1` and `arr2` in the `merge` method defeats its purpose.
- you must use a separate index for the destination array.
- you should stop comparing elements when you reach the end of either array
- you should deal with remaining elements separately.

Here is a corrected version of the `merge` method:

```java
public class Assignment8Code 
{   
    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {
        // Allocate a new array that will fit the length of the two given arrays
        int[] sortedArray = new int[(arr1.length + arr2.length)];

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int index3 = 0;

        // Merge the sorted arrays
        while (index1 < arr1.length && index2 < arr2.length)
        {
            //Check to see which array starts with the higher number
            if (arr1[index1] <= arr2[index2])
            {
                sortedArray[index3++] = arr1[index1++];
            }
            else
            {
                sortedArray[index3++] = arr2[index2++];
            }
        }
        // Append the remaining elements 
        while (index1 < arr1.length)
        {
            sortedArray[index3++] = arr1[index1++];
        }
        while (index2 < arr2.length)
        {
            sortedArray[index3++] = arr2[index2++];
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }
}
```

Note that this approach is quite inefficient as it allocates a new array for each merge. Implementing mergesort this way for large arrays would allocating a substantial amount of mmemory (log2(N) * N integers) causing unnecessary stress on the garbage collector. Using a single temporary array for the whole mergesort would be much more efficient but require a different `merge` method.